# Mock default parameter value in inner function

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-mock, pytest-mock

I have the following (simplified) piece of code:

```py
def get_redis()
  return redis_instance


def bar(key, value, redis=get_redis())
  redis.set(key, value)


def foo()
  bar("key", value)
```

In my test I want to mock the function `get_redis` to return an instance of `fakeredis.FakeStrictRedis()`, so I did this

```py
def test_foo(mocker):
  mocker.patch("app.main.get_redis", return_value=fakeredis.FakeStrictRedis())
  foo()
```

the mocked function has no effect, the `foo` function try to connect to real redis using the get_redis function from main.

If I wrote in this way works

```py
def bar(key, value)
  redis=get_redis()
  redis.set(key, value)
```

This works, but I can pass redis as default value. How can I mock?

Comment: I wouldn't mock at all. `foo` requires a Redis instance, if only to pass to `bar`, so make it a parameter. Then you can simply pass your fake instance as an argument rather than patching anything.

Comment: I can't pass a redis instance to `foo` because its a RPC method

Comment: an alternative is make a global variable of redis, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just modify the `bar` function slightly as follows so that your functions don't get called before the mock can be applied:

```
def bar(key, value, redis=get_redis)
    if callable(redis):
        redis = redis()
    redis.set(key, value)
```

Writing the function this way means that your mock will apply at the time the function is called, and not at startup before any mocks can be applied.  In short, writing `bar` this way, ensures the return of `get_redis` it will propagate through your `bar` function every time the function is called .

Comment: This doesn't work, it still calls the original `get_redis` because the default value still evaluates to the original function.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your mock, but you seem to be misunderstanding how default parameter values work. As explained in [the Python Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions), **default parameter values are evaluated when the function *definition* is executed**.

In your case, this means that the original `get_redis` is called already when `bar` is defined:

```py
def bar(key, value, redis=get_redis()):
```

This statement is executed when `pytest` imports your module, i.e., before `test_foo` is executed, so mocking `get_redis` in the test has no effect because it's already too late by then.

To make the default-supplying factory function mockable, use `None` as the default and make the function call the factory unless another value was specified in the call:

```py
def bar(key, value, redis=None)
  redis = redis or get_redis()
  redis.set(key, value)
```